# Puppeteer - best standard practices

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

What is the best (or standard) way to do common operations on puppeteer?

Consider this:

```
<div class="C1">
    <img alt="Bla Bla" class="C2" scrset="lots of stuff here" scr="THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT">
```

I want to acces the src text. What is the best way to do that?

Or another situation where i have this on the webpage:

```
<a class="D1 D2 D3" role="button" </a>
```

And i want to check the existence (and nonexistence) of an element like the above button.

Comment: It's hard to say about best practices because puppeteer is pretty new. The best option is doing as it is in the official documentation if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of my asnwer was correclt solved by Carsten and i thank him very much!

However, his solution for the first part was not working.

Here's how i got it to work:

```
const values = await page.evaluate(
        () => [...document.querySelectorAll('.C2')]
        .map(element => element.getAttribute('src'))
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your first example (getting the src text):**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(`insertYourURLhere.com`, {
        timeout: 0,
        waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded']
    })
    
    // getting a handle on the div first
    const outerDiv = await page.$('div.C1')
    // proceeding from the selected div
    const scrAttribut = await outerDiv.$eval('img.C2', el => el.getAttribute('scr'))

    console.log(scrAttribut)
    
    browser.close()
}

run()
```

**Your second example (checking the existence of an element):**

You use the same method as shown above for the outer div to find your button:

```
page.$(selector)
```

Then you check the return value.

> *If no element matches the selector, the return value resolve to* null.

From: [Puppeteer documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.5.0&show=api-pageselector)

Comment: Thank you so much! About checking the existence of an element.... Is it dynamic? Meaning if i run this on a dynamic element and its there. Then if the element is removed, will it detect that it is no longer there without reloading the page?

Comment: I tried the first part and i get an error:


(node:7140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: outerDiv.$eval is not a
 function
(node:7140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:7140) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Comment: If page.$(selector) does not find an element is returns null. Then null.$eval() is not a function. elementhandle.$eval() is a function on the elementhandle that you get back from page.$(selector) if it finds an element.

Comment: The checking of the existence by using page.$(selector) is not dynamic. It returns a promise, if there is no matching element it returns null. Otherwise you get an elementHandle.

Comment: I make sure that these tags exist in my HTML. Though i always seem to get that error...

Comment: Would you post your real HTML and not the abstract example please? And maybe your puppeteer code as well.

Comment: div class="A1" style="padding-bottom: 124.907%;">
 <img alt="" class="Kh2" decoding="auto" sizes="479px" srcset="noise_here" src="https://link_to_sit.com/1.jpg" style=""></div>

Comment: const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: false                 
            });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://link_to_site.com/htm', {
        timeout: 0,
        waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded']
    });

    const outerDiv = await page.$('div.A1');
    const scrAttribut = await outerDiv.$eval('img.Kh2', el => el.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(scrAttribut);
    browser.close();
}

run();